# How to get a v2 jwt token when authorizing against AzureAD in Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, postman

I'm able to get a [v1.0 jwt token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens) with the below settings.

How do I make the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` endpoint return v2.0?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we need to create app in ad with "Supported account types" as `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)`.(when we choose this option, the property `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in its Manifest will be `2`).
[image]

Then we need to add a scope in it, and when we request the access token, we need to use `openid api://xxxxxx/User.read` instead of only `openid` in postman as the screenshot you provided.

After that, we can request the access token(v2)
[image]

Parse the access token, it will show v2.
[image]

**Update about how to add scope:**

We can add the scope in app on portal(shown as screenshot below):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Then we can copy the scope directly from here as below:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a v2 token? As that seems pretty much the same as what I'm doing. I'm just using the postman wizard to generate the call. If you put that token into https://jwt.io/ does it say `"ver": "1.0",` or `"ver": "2.0",`?

Comment: Hi @Snæbjørn I have update my answer, please check the "Update".

Comment: @Snæbjørn Sorry there is something wrong in the update I provide before. I got the id token v2 but not access token v2 in the update before. I have modified the answer and removed all of the useless content. Please check.

Comment: Hi @Snæbjørn May I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution works fine, could you please mark it as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: Sorry, wasn't able to test before today. Adding User.Read didn't help. Our account type is Single Tenant and I can't change that. The `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` is null. But here's the strange part. When using https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js that is able to fetch a v2 token from it. Or... perhaps it's able to convert it. Because I've noticed it sends a v1 token when interacting with the MS Graph API

Comment: Hi @Snæbjørn I test it in my side, I can edit the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` from null to `2` even if the account type is single tenant. And then request the access token, its version become 2.0

Comment: @Snæbjørn If you are not allowed to change `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to 2, please pay attention to the value of property `signInAudience`. It may cause this problem.

Comment: I changed `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to 2 but I'm still getting a v1. I tried removng all cookies and logged out, even got another person to try it on another computer and he also got a v1 :(

Comment: BTW what is the xxxxxx in api://xxxxxx/User.read? Neither my client id or tenant id work. But I can just write `user.read` however that still returns a v1 token

Comment: Hi @Snæbjørn It seems you are not clear about how to add a scope in app. The uri `api://xxxxxx/User.read` should be added in scope and be generated automatically but not combined by us. I'm sorry that steps I provided before was not detailed enough. I have update the answer, please check the "Update about how to add scope".

Comment: Hi @Snæbjørn Does this help your problem ?

Comment: Thank you so much! Manually adding the magic User.Read scope made it return a v2 jwt token! I'm very confused as to why adding a scope changes the token version.

Answer (score 1):

For me setting "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2 in the manifest solved the issue. No further changes to the app registration was required.

Comment: Thanks, with this you can use the new Authentication method for Azure Functions (instead of classic)