# Azure AD Authentication Token not authorized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created an API and am expecting an access token from Azure AD:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();

            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);


        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                options.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}";

            });
```

Then I created a SPA on React using MSAL, but when I login the access token returned from MSAL is not accepted on my API:

```js
function RequestProfileData() {
   
    instance.acquireTokenSilent({
        ...loginRequest,
        account: accounts[0]
    }).then((response) => {
        debugger;
        const api = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'https://localhost:44312',
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${response.accessToken}`
            }
        });
        
        
        api.get('/WeatherForecast').then(result => {
            debugger;
            console.log(result.data)
        });
    
    })
```

My MSAL configuration is:

```js
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "ClientId",
        authority: "https://sts.windows.net/TenantId/",
        tenantId: "TenantId",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
            "
    },
    cashe: {
        casheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookkie: false
    },
}

export const loginRequest = {
    scope: ['api://ClientId/Read']
}
```

Comment: May I know how you get the token?

Comment: I use MSAL, here's my code   const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  <Button onClick={() => instance.loginPopup(loginRequest)}>Login</Button>

Configuration : msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "clientId",
        authority: "https://sts.windows.net/APITenantId/",
        tenantId: "API TenantId",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
        client_Secret: "ClientSecret"
    },
    cashe: {
        casheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookkie: false
    },
}

export const loginRequest = {
    scope: ['api://clientId/Read']
}

Comment: sorry im a beginer :(

Comment: May I know if the clientId value in code  scope: ['api://clientId/Read']  the same as in server side : options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"]; ?

Comment: yes its the same

Comment: And any exception information?

Comment: createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401

Comment: it seems the token return from my login not accepting. but when i try to get Token from Here:    


            var adCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenanId");
            var token = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(clientId, adCred);
            var accesstoken = token.AccessToken;

its working fine

Comment: I noticed your server application exposed a Scope to your SPA client application,if client-cred tokens could be accepted but the token that obtains from user login flow is not, could you please have a check that have you granted user Delegated permissions to your SPA client AD application? You can grant permissions on Azure Portal =>Azure AD => App registrations=> find your SPA app=>API permissions=>add a permission => My APIs to find the Read permission to grant.

Comment: @StillANoob Could you please tell me if you can call the API with postman : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084891/how-to-get-a-v2-jwt-token-when-authorizing-against-azuread-in-postman/61092349#61092349?

Comment: You should grant delegated permissions to spa apps, not application permissions. This permission is exposed by your server application.

Comment: @JimXu I can't call the API because it requires an authentication on azure ad.

Comment: @CarlZhao: how to delegate permission on my SPA?

Comment: @JimXu: Yes I added API permission my on SPA

Comment: @StillANoob Please upyour code as `services.AddAuthentication(x =>{x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>{x.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/v2.0";x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = false,
                  ValidAudiences = new[] { "<client id>", "api://<client id>" }
              };
          })` in StartUp.cs.

Comment: @JimXu: I replace my code to the code you gave but the token from SPA still encounter 401. 

Should I use ClientID and Tenant ID of API to SPA?

Comment: @StillANoob Could you please parse the token you get in spa vai https://jwt.ms and provide the screenshot of it?

Comment: "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/805f5242-924a-44da-b4fa-a2029a97cbf6/",
  "iat": 1614759463,
  "nbf": 1614759463,
  "exp": 1614763363,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "acrs": [
    "urn:user:registersecurityinfo",
    "urn:microsoft:req1",
    "urn:microsoft:req2",
    "urn:microsoft:req3",
    "c1",
    "c2",
    "c3",
    "c4",
    "c5",
    "c6",
    "c7",
    "c8",
    "c9",
    "c10",
    "c11",
    "c12",
    "c13",
    "c14",
    "c15",
    "c16",
    "c17",
    "c18",
    "c19",
    "c20",
    "c21",
    "c22",
    "c23",
    "c24",
    "c25"
  ],

Comment: "aio": "ASQA2/8TAAAAUnqRuYLhxtN9XcO8et+anZeynIx4kEqhGYqZWJHwE/U=",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "frontend",
  "appid": "700f0ca5-1cd2-4d2d-87d9-3856efb2dc83",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "114.108.219.72",
  "name": "test",
  "oid": "6503b4e9-16a0-40cd-952b-58bbf7d2b1f3",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "100320011D6114D8",
  "rh": "0.AAAAQlJfgEqS2kS0-qICmpfL9qUMD3DSHC1Nh9k4Vu-y3INxANw.",

Comment: "scp": "User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email",
  "sub": "DrWaXq0kESQPVkAoLUhFm6F5h046bGE8RyXK9CH6Ibg",
  "tenant_region_scope": "AS",
  "tid": "805f5242-924a-44da-b4fa-a2029a97cbf6",
  "unique_name": "test@onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "test@onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "HyR-dhBxHEeyqOW8ibcXAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10",
    "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3",
    "b79fbf4d-3ef9-4689-8143-76b194e85509"
  ],
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "gxrTeQGmMvdkseowAufVlwXImB-DNV2R3k0WYWaJd6A"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1613671244
}

Comment: sorry dont know how to attach screenshot

Comment: @StillANoob Could you provide the value of  token claim `aud`? Besides, How you get token in your application?

Comment: @JimXu I use Msal on my SPA and once I login it will return a access token. 

Also, even i use my client Id and tenant ID same on my API the return access token from Msal still not authenticated. not sure why

Comment: heres the aud : 700f0ca5-1cd2-4d2d-87d9-3856efb2dc83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

### Register the service in Azure AD

1. Navigate to the Microsoft identity platform for developers [App registrations](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908) page.
2. Select **New registration**.
3. When the **Register an application page** appears, enter your application's registration information:

   - In the **Name** section, enter a meaningful application name that will be displayed to users of the app, for example `ProfileAPI`.
   - Change **Supported account types** to **Personal Microsoft accounts only**.
   - Select **Register** to create the application.
4. On the app **Overview** page, find the **Application (client) ID** value and record it for later. You'll need it to configure the configuration file for this projects.
5. Select the **Expose an API** section, and:

   - Click **Set** next to the Application ID URI to generate a URI that is unique for this app (in the form of `api://{clientId}`).
   - Select **Add a scope**
   - Enter the following parameters

     - for **Scope name** use `access_as_user`
     - Keep **Admins and users** for **Who can consent**
     - in **User consent display name** type `Access ProfileAPI as a user`
     - in **User consent description** type `Accesses the ProfileAPI web API as a user`
     - Keep **State** as **Enabled**
     - Select **Add scope**

### Register the client

1. Navigate to the Microsoft identity platform for developers [App registrations](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908) page.
2. Select **New registration**.
3. When the **Register an application page** appears, enter your application's registration information:

   - In the **Name** section, enter a meaningful application name that will be displayed to users of the app, for example `ProfileSPA`.
   - Change **Supported account types** to **Accounts in this organizational directory only**.
   - Select **Register** to create the application.
4. On the app **Overview** page, find the **Application (client) ID** value and record it for later. You'll need it to configure the configuration file for this projects.
5. From the app's Overview page, select the **Authentication** section.

   - Click **Add a platform** button.
   - Select **Single-page Applications** on the right blade.
   - Add a **Redirect URIs**, for instance `http://localhost:3000`.
   - Click **Configure**.
6. Select the **API permissions** section

   - Click the **Add a permission** button and then,
   - Ensure that the **My APIs** tab is selected
   - In the list of APIs, select the `ProfileAPI` API, or the name you entered for the web API
   - In the **Delegated permissions** section, ensure that the right permissions are checked: **access_as_user**. Use the search box if necessary.
   - Select the **Add permissions** button.

### Configure Client Application

Regarding how to configure Azure AD in react application, please refer to [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react)

### Configure Server application

1. Update appsetting.json

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "[Client_id-of-web-api-eg-2ec40e65-ba09-4853-bcde-bcb60029e596]",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "Audience": "custom App ID URI for your web API"
  },
  // more lines
}
```

2. Install package `Microsoft.Identity.Web`
3. Update startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // Since IdentityModel version 5.2.1 (or since Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer version 2.2.0),
                // PII hiding in log files is enabled by default for GDPR concerns.
                // For debugging/development purposes, one can enable additional detail in exceptions by setting IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII to true.
                // Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-overview)

Comment: When I replace the startup.cs, the API is accessible even it doesn't have token.

Comment: @StillANoob Have you add `[Authorize]` on your controller?